# Does CSS Background Image Repeat increases the Load on Page?

Tags: html, css

Say an Image of 1px width and 20px height of size 1kb is repeated in an unordered list item of with 10px.
Then will the page size in terms of kb is increased by 10kb (width of listitem* Size of Image) or it will be 1kb only.?

Comment: This image is in cache, so only 1 kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only making one request to the server for that one background image once, so no, it won't increase the page size.

Images such as the one you suggest are an ideal way to reduce page size.

If you want to go further you could consider using CSS sprites to further cut down on page size and loading time.

Answer (score 2):

The downloaded page size will not change (that is, of the HTML and images).

Since it is the *same* image, it will be reused from the single download.

In memory, however, there will be an increase as the background needs to be rendered. It is not possible to determine what kind of memory increase this will cause.

Comment: Your ans is some what confusing. Can you please elaborate? "In memory, however, there will be an increase as the background needs to be rendered."

Comment: When anything renderes in the browser, it requires memory. Displaying the same images in 10 places will require more memory than displaying it in one.

Comment: but @Kyle Sevenoaks says that the Image will get loaded in browser's cache and how come it requires memory to display the cached image?

Comment: @hungrycoder - Browser cache and system memory are different things.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not increase the size. It will remain 1kb in size.

> "Basically, Image slicing is useful for breaking up huge images so that the individual pieces will load more quickly than the whole large one."

Answer (score 1):

The image gets loaded into the browser's cache only once. So the loaded amount will only be 1kb. This is why spritesheets are such a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

No not at all it's not increase the loading page time. Image is loaded only onces.

Answer (score 1):

absolutely not
when browser download the background,it repeat the background with the downloaded background image and never download multiple times,you can check it with firebug